# Image Title/Description Not Appearing In Media Gallery Lightbox

Tags: module, drupal-7, gallery, media, colorbox

I'm using the media gallery module for Drupal (http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery). I have a gallery set up, and all of the images have titles and descriptions. When I click an image in the gallery, a lightbox opens up and shows the image, but it doesn't display the title nor the description. When I click the image inside the lightbox, I'm taken to another page where the image is shown again, this time with the title and description.

I need to know if there's a way to do one of the following, and if so, how to do it.

1. Is there a way to get the image title and description to display in the media gallery lightbox? (Currently, the lightbox displays navigation arrows, a slideshow link, a close button, and "Item X of Y")
2. Is there a way to take the user to the detail page directly instead of opening up the lightbox?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the 'Edit gallery' tab make sure the 'Show title and description' checkbox is checked like this:

[image]

Once the titles/descriptions are set to show (and you probably already know this, since you have the titles and descriptions showing in the actual pages), you can add or modify the titles/descriptions by going to the 'Edit media' tab.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason, the presentations settings section was set as hidden. But when I unhid them, I was able to change the settings and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: EDIT: Looks like they only want the description and not the title. Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: Not through the admin interface (as you can see).  You can use css to hide the title portion if you have your own custom theme on the site that you can add to...